# Rewriting left join as a where clause for indexed view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```sql
SELECT
    *
--  cd.CountId,
--  cd.ApproachId,
--  c .CountId,
--  c .IntersectionId,
--  l .IntersectionId,
--  l .ApproachId
FROM
    dbo.CountData AS cd

    INNER JOIN dbo."Count" AS c ON
        cd.CountId = c.CountId

    LEFT JOIN dbo.Leg AS l ON
        c.IntersectionId = l.IntersectionId
        AND
        cd.ApproachId = l.ApproachId 

WHERE
    l.IntersectionId IS NULL
```

How can I rewrite this query such that no `LEFT JOIN` is involved?

The end goal is to have a query that is acceptable as an indexed view ([as indexed views cannot use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, `FULL OUTER JOIN`, nor subqueries and derived-tables](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/11/what-you-can-and-cant-do-with-indexed-views/)).

Comment: and why do you want an indexed view?

Comment: because I want to write a complicated constraint https://spaghettidba.com/2011/08/03/enforcing-complex-constraints-with-indexed-views/ that uses the non-existance of a value to enforce a violation of the uniqueness

Comment: something tells me you are solving this the wrong way.

Comment: FYI, you can make a function that can be used as a constraint. What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: This has all the tell tale signs of being an xy problem. http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Indexing/indexedviewswithouterjoins/1884/

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean using functions in a constraint is inherently prone to many issues. I found issues where the query optimizer will ignore a constraint when a function is used.  The linked sql constraint via unique indexed views is AFAIK more or less how FKs work and aren't prone to all the issues of functions

Comment: @CuriousDeveloper I've not seen a problem with a well written function in a constraint. Perhaps you can expand on why a function can't work in your question.

Comment: The function may work but can stop working when the query optimizer may find a new way to optimize a query. Using functions are also quite slow. One example of this behavior is  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054748/check-constraint-does-not-work-on-bulk-insert-for-more-than-250-records and there are numerous articles about avoiding functions in constraints.  I avoid function constants all together now and try to use FKs when I can in the design, in this case I cant use a FK because of multiple tables